# Apache cordova please install android target 22

Tags: android, apache, cordova, web-applications

I have installed android 22.

[image]

I have apache ant installed

[image]

I have sent path for android home, java home too.

But still I get the below error when I try to build the android app.

[image]

android manifest file

[image]

Comment: what happens if you write "android" con the CMD?

Comment: #jcesarmobile nothing happens to me oif I write android. Should I ut anything in the path?

Comment: Yes nothing happens to me too. But the problem is with the path settings. Be sure to set up the JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME path.